# How do I migrate feed_dict and placeholder to TensorFlow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to convert a simple snippet from TensorFlow 1.x to TensorFlow 2:

```py
# ########## TensorFlow 1.x code: ##########
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

coefficients = np.array([[1.], [-10.], [25.]])
w = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3, 1])
cost = (x[0][0] * (w**2)) + (x[1][0]*w) + (x[2][0])
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cost)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    session = tf.Session()
    session.run(init)

    for i in range(100):
        session.run(train, feed_dict={x: coefficients})

    print(session.run(w))
```

Much of the old API has been replaced in TF2 (e.g. `GradientDescentOptimizer` replaced with `keras.optimizers.SGD`), and I was able to figure out how to refactor most of my code, but I don't know how to refactor `tf.placeholder` and `feed_dict` and how those two interact. Is the use of placeholders simply eschewed in TF2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you use `@tf.function` and turn placeholders into function arguments. `sess.run` then is replaced with calling that function. Things that used to return ops (like `minimize`) are now just called inside the function. Here's your snippet converted:

```
coefficients = tf.constant([[1.], [-10.], [25.]])
w = tf.Variable(0.0)

@tf.function
def train(x):
  cost = (x[0][0] * (w**2)) + (x[1][0]*w) + (x[2][0])
  tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cost, var_list=[w])

for i in range(100):
    train(coefficients)

print(w)
```

As you mentioned, `train.GradientDescentOptimizer` is deprecated, so upgrading that part will need a few more changes.